# Excel - return all unique permutations of 3 columns

Tags: excel, function

I have 3 columns

`a     b   c`

`jon  ben  2`

`ben  jon  2`

`roy  jack 1`

`jack roy  1`

I'm trying to retrieve all unique permutations e.g. `ben` and `jon` = `jon` and `ben` so they should only appear once. Expected output:

`a   b   c`

`jon  ben  2`

`roy  jack 1`

Any ideas of a function that could do this? The order in the output does not matter. I've tried concatenating and then removing duplicates, but obviously this only considers the string order.

I've created a fourth column by joining all three columns together `=a1&","&b1&","&c1` and used excel's built in remove duplicates function. This doesnt work as the order of the strings are different.

Comment: Are you trying to do this via a formula, or VBA?  Also, while it may not have worked, can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Create a helper column that sorts the two strings alphabetically. Then the things you tried before will work.

Comment: @brucewayne via formula. i'll edit it now

Comment: @DougGlancy i'm not sure i understand what you mean

Comment: Use the fact that Jon> Ben is true to sort and concatenate the two names in a separate column. Sorry, I'm on my phone or I'd just answer.

Comment: what is column C number for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your forth column use the formula

```
=if(A1<B1,A1&","&B1&","&C1,B1&","&A1&","&C1)
```

Which should join A and B in alphabetical order, then you can remove duplicates as you have done.